# Use a integer variable in python without the quotes

Tags: python

I am manipulating a string to return just a number within the string. The basic code below

```
partition_tuple_se = searchterm.rpartition('S')
partition_tuple_sea = partition_tuple_se[2].rpartition('E')
season = partition_tuple_sea[0]
print season
```

When I print it comes out as a number 9. As soon as I use the variable season in an API call

```
t = tvdb_api.Tvdb()
episode = t[name][season][14]
print episode['overview']
```

it returns as '9' which breaks the API call because it expects 9. How to I get around this?

Comment: I am a little surprised that that didn't show up in the first Google result.

Comment: @mattbornski, master of understatement.

Comment: I tried google but I guess I wasn't searching for the right thing. Sometimes the community is more power than google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it to the `int` constructor.

```
>>> int('9')
9
```

Answer (score 1):

```
season = int(partition_tuple_sea[0])
```

should do the job if I understand the problem and question correctly.